# How to edit, delete, sort the rows in Oracle SQL Developer for mysql?

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running MySQL on Oracle SQL Developer. Through Tools -> preferences, I added a JAR for MySQL.
Now when I am opening a connection and trying to edit the data in rows of tables, it dies not allow.
I am just able to read the table data. Not able to edit, delete, apply filter etc operations.Please let me know if there is any solution for the same.

Comment: Do you have mysql privileges to  edit, delete?

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps to edit/delete rows from a table in Oracle **SQL Developer**:

1. Expand **connections**, and select your database connection.
2. Expand the **Tables**, remove any filters if applied.
3. Just click on the table name you want to edit, or right-click and select **Edit**.

[image]

4. It will open the table in Edit tab.

[image]

5. Now, select **Data** tab in the table properties:

[image]

6. Now, double-click on any particular value to Edit it, it will open the **Edit Value** box:

[image]

7. Edit the value, and click **OK**.
8. To **delete**, select a row and click on the "**X**" symbol:

[image]

9. It will highlight the row to be deleted in **Red**.
10. Just click on **Commit changes** to complete the transaction:

[image]

Comment: @abdulrehmankk That means the "user" you have logged in doesn't have the necessary privileges.

Comment: i am login from root user

Comment: @abdulrehmankk Did you open the table in separate edit tab or not? Step 1-4